# GetByteAsArray() takes long time

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I'm trying to generate excel (.xlsx) file and store it using EPPLUS for some huge records (around 20k rows and 1.5k columns).

When I use EPPLUS 3.0.0.2 I can not create excel file due to `OutOfMemory` issue, and now I'm using EPPLUS 4.0.2 and I can generate excel file.

The issue is a normal report with 15k rows and 0.5k columns takes 4-5 minutes in 3.0.0.2 and in 4.0.2 it takes around 15 minutes for the same.

Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
Byte[] bin = p.GetAsByteArray(); //p is ExcelPackage
string excelfile = PATH + "\\" + ExcelFilename + ".xlsx";
File.WriteAllBytes(excelfile, bin);
```

Comment: You could/should use a performance profiler like e.g. [ANTS from Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Comment: Maybe this question should be directed to the creators of EPPLUS.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Why i need a Performance Profiler?

Comment: Can you show us any more of your code? There might be some memory issues elsewhere.

Comment: Unqualified guess: It's the memory allocation :-). The new version uses a temp file on disk to work around the memory issues of the first one.